# word game samples for wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an idea for a word game for WP7.  Can someone point me to some good samples of word games to get me started in the right direction?

The game is along the lines of a HangMan game so I will need to pick characters from the albhabet set.

Pratik

Answer (score 0):

There are already games like this in the [marketplace](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8mA_BWoKDs). There is no single recipe that will help you build a game like that at the moment, but I would recommend starting with some game development tutorials [here](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/roadmap).

What you're looking for is basic keyboard input or simulated input (can be passed as a sequence of button clicks).